# Determining the state of a UISwitch when the UITableCell it is on is clicked

Tags: uitableview, uiswitch, didselectrowatindexpath

I a newb to IOS programming and I'm having a problem.  I've got a table view that I dynamically load with a UISwitch in each cell using the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
self.myNewSwitch = mySwitch;
[mySwitch release];
[cell setAccessoryView: self.myNewSwitch];
[(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

That works fine.  When I click on the switch, the code in changeState runs fine.

Here's where my problem is.  When the user presses a cell in the table, I want to see what state the switch is in (On or Off).  My problem is that I can not figure out how to determine that in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath code.  I can determine the correct cell, but I couldn't find out how to access the switch that is on that cell when I searched using Google.  Here's my code for  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //If the on/off switch is on, go to the probes page.  if off, do not do anything
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   //Determine the switch state here.    
    UISwitch *theSwitch;
    theSwitch = ???????  //<- What do I do???

    if (theSwitch.isOn) {
      //define the probes view controller
      Probes *detailViewController = [[Probes alloc] initWithNibName:@"Probes" bundle:nil];
      //pass in the ip address
      detailViewController.lblIPAddr = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
      [detailViewController release];
    }
    //Deselect this row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Any help/code will be helpful.

-NCGrimbo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //If the on/off switch is on, go to the probes page.  if off, do not do anything
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   //Determine the switch state here.         

    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView ;       

    if (theSwitch.isOn) {
      //define the probes view controller
      Probes *detailViewController = [[Probes alloc] initWithNibName:@"Probes" bundle:nil];
      //pass in the ip address
      detailViewController.lblIPAddr = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
      [detailViewController release];
    }
    //Deselect this row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

but I don't know why you are using,

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
self.myNewSwitch = mySwitch;
[mySwitch release];
[cell setAccessoryView: self.myNewSwitch];
```

every time you make new UITableViewCell, self.myNewSwitch is same UISwitch (Last UiSwitch).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It works great.  As for the question you asked me, this is the way I was shown by another developer.  If there is a better way, please let me know.